# How to randomly sample elements between 2 rows in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe `df` in the following format:

```
   ColumnA.     ColumnB.      IsMatching
0 sadasdsad.    asdsadsad      True
1 asdsadsadas.  asdsadasd.     False
2 asdsadasd.    asdsadsad.     False
3 dfsdfsdfi     ijijiiijj.     False
4 sdasdsads.    asdsadsad      True
5 dfsdfsdfi     ijijiiijj.     False
6 jijijijij.    ijijijiji.     False
7 assdssads.    asd222sad      True
```

I would like to create a new dataframe, say `new_df`, which contains `n` randomly sampled rows with `IsMatching == False` from the original `df` between `2` `True` instances. For example, randomly select `n` rows between indices `0` and `4`, similarly randomly select `n` rows between indices `4` and `7` etc.

A sample desired output for `new_df` would be (with sampling `2` rows randomly between the `True` instances in `df`). Note that it is possible that there is less than 2 rows between True instances - and in that case I would like the `new_df` to have whatever rows are there.

```
1 asdsadsadas.  asdsadasd.     False
3 dfsdfsdfi     ijijiiijj.     False
5 dfsdfsdfi     ijijiiijj.     False
6 jijijijij.    ijijijiji.     False
```

I searched about the `df.sample()` method in `Pandas`, but it doesn't seem to have a provision **to sample between 2 rows**. Any help and suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Post what you want new_df to look like.

Comment: @elPastor I have added the desired sample output. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```py
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO("""
 ColumnA.     ColumnB.      IsMatching
0 sadasdsad.    asdsadsad      True
1 asdsadsadas.  asdsadasd.     False
2 asdsadasd.    asdsadsad.     False
3 dfsdfsdfi     ijijiiijj.     False
4 sdasdsads.    asdsadsad      True
5 dfsdfsdfi     ijijiiijj.     False
6 jijijijij.    ijijijiji.     False
7 assdssads.    asd222sad      True
""")

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep='\s+')

df['between_rows_group'] = df['IsMatching'].cumsum()

# take 1 sample
df.query('IsMatching==False').groupby('between_rows_group').sample(1)

# take samples with replacement
df.query('IsMatching==False').groupby('between_rows_group').sample(5, replace=True)

# take as many samples as are possible 
df.query('IsMatching==False').groupby('between_rows_group').apply(lambda x: x.sample(min(5, len(x)))).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. However, it seems to only sample 1 row? When I use something like this `df.query('IsMatching==False').groupby('between_rows_group').sample(10)` to sample more rows - I get an error `ValueError: Cannot take a larger sample than population when 'replace=False'`. Is there a way to avoid this problem (as there may be cases when there are not 10 rows in between 2 rows - in that case it should select whatever the rows in between are). Thanks!
.

Comment: if you want to sample 10 rows, then pass `replace=True` option. Without replacement, it's not feasible to sample more observations than there are in the underlying data.

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to also take as many samples as possible (so without replacement, but taking into account the varying number of rows)